# Disabling the expansion of certain macros in error/warning outputs

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I have a very frequently used, somewhat complex macro (let's call it `MAC(...)` for the sake of this question), which must be a macro (as it's very type-generic). The macro behaves syntactically, like a function call but internally calls over 10 other macros.

Consequently if I make an error while calling `MAC()` e.g., if I do:
`MAC(1-)` gcc/clang will dump at me the quite long preprocessor stack trace of `MAC()` which I'm not at all intersted in.

If I define MAC() like so:

```
#if DEBUG_MAC
    int MAC(); //so I get a nice preprocessor stack trace
#else
    #define MAC(...) //here would come the actual definition
#endif
```

and then, upon encountering an error I recompile with `-DDEBUG_MAC`, I get a nice (=nonexistent) preprocessor stack trace but this approach feels clumsy and only works for diagnosing hard errors, not warnings.

Is there a way to get gcc or clang to behave like this, i.e., treat a macro like an opaque function call for the purposes of error reporting,  without doing this kind of declaration/macro shuffling?

Comment: Are the "in expansion of macro" notes insufficient for your needs ? Or are they not appearing ? Or is it that you don't want those at all ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker They are appearing and that's the problem. I want to disable them for this particular, very frequently used, macro -- make it seem as if the macro were a function.

Comment: does [`-ftrack-macro-expansion=0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#index-ftrack-macro-expansion) do what you need ? It wouldn't be selective for a specific macro though.

Comment: A bit hard to understand: do you want to debug the actual parameter list of your macro? Is it that? Which properties does it fulfill in the non-error case, and vice versa which errors are most common? Incomplete expressions like the `1-`? And the problem is the clutter in error messages?